# Detecting turning of laptop lid and device orientation

Tags: arch-linux, laptop, touch-screen, tablet, acer

I'm using Arch Linux on an Acer Spin 5 laptop. The laptop lid can be turned backwards and then be used as a tablet. In Windows this is detected automatically and the keyboard is deactivated then. Arch seems to detect this, too, because when I turn the screen about 180° the keyboard gets deactivated, too.

I have tried to read out `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` (with a script) when the lid is turned more 180°, but the state is still just "open" then. So how can I detect whether the lid is just open or open more than 180°?

Also Windows seems to be able to detect the device orientation and adjusts screen orientation accordingly (like holding it sideways), is it possible, to detect this in Arch, too?

Comment: Does anything appear in the `dmesg` output, or the `systemd` journal (`journalctl`), when you turn the lid?

Comment: No, nothing appears there.

Comment: When the keyboard is deactivated, is it just X that stops receiving its input, or the consoles (tty1 etc) too?  We need to work out at what level this deactivation occurs, and what event triggers it.

Comment: I logged out of i3 and tried it. The keyboard gets deactivated on tty1 as well.